# Filters and groups Odoo 10

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I have several filters written this way:

--> For a classic filter

```
<filter string="Pas inscrit restauration scolaire" name="pasinscritcantine" domain="[('half_pension','=',False)]"></filter>
```

--> For a filter grouped by

```
<filter string="Restauration Scolaire" name="demipension" domain="[]" context="{'group_by':'half_pension'}"></filter>
```

I can not find documentation on the visibility of filters (access) for certain groups.

Let me explain :

These filters work perfectly when I am logged in as an administrator.
On the other hand when I am with a lambda user, I do not see them.
I have created a School Restore group to give rights to certain views or models but the filters are not taken into account. How can I view these two filters in the School Restore group?

thank you in advance

Comment: no one for help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add a groups attribute on your filters ? Like this : https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/aide-1/question/create-a-view-for-a-specific-user-group-56572#answer_56575

Comment: Hello, Yes. For views it's perfect but for filters, it does not work